# How to disable mousewheel in MudBlazor's MudNumericField

Tags: mudblazor

my MudNumericField look like this:

```
<MudNumericField @bind-Value="To" Label="To" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Step="1M" ReadOnly="true" HideSpinButtons="true" />
```

Despite being **Readonly** I can change its value using mousewheel (pressing shift key). Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's likely a bug. It has been resolved in **6.0.5** version of **Mudblazor** however.

Source: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/releases/tag/v6.0.5